# How to retrieve $key as to $row data from Laravel MySQL loop conditional aggregate?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

In order to shorten the database calls, a conditional aggregate command was suggested to me but it does not reference how to use the Laravel/PHP/Mysql data retrieval method I'm using.

I may just be understanding this wrong or using the wrong method to retrieve data, but the following produces errors when used to pull specific column data:

```
foreach($cargodb->get_results(
    "
    SELECT 
        terminal, 
        month, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN year = YEAR(CURDATE())     THEN tonneCount ELSE 0 END) tonnage_cy,
        SUM(CASE WHEN year = YEAR(CURDATE()) - 1 THEN tonneCount ELSE 0 END) tonnage_ly
    FROM volumes
    WHERE year >= YEAR(CURDATE()) - 1
    GROUP BY terminal, month
    ORDER BY month desc
    "
)  as $key => $row) {
    $tonnages = $row->tonneCount;
    $terminal = $row->terminal;
    $year = $row->year;
    $month = $row->month;
    $cargovolume_cy[] = 
    '<h4 class="cv-terminal-title">'.$terminal.' </h4>'. 
    '<div class="cargovolumes_cy">'.
    '<div class="cargovolumes_cy-dates cvrow-'.$month.'-'.$year.'">'.
    '<span class="cy-month"> '.$month.' </span>'. 
    '<span class="cy-year"> '.$year.' </span></div>'. 
    '<div class="cy-year-bar"><div class="cy-tonnage-bar">&nbsp;</div>'.
    '<span class="cy-tonnage" value="'.$tonnages.'"> '.$tonnages.' </span></div>'.
    '</div>';
    $cargovolume_ly[] = 
    // '<br />';
    '<div class="cargovolumes_ly">'. 
    '<div class="cargovolumes_ly-dates">'.
    '<span class="ly-month"> '.$month.' </span>'. 
    '<span class="ly-year"> '.$year.' </span></div>'. 
    '<div class="ly-year-bar"><div class="ly-tonnage-bar">&nbsp;</div>'.
    '<span class="ly-tonnage" value="'.$tonnages.'"> '.$tonnages.' </span></div>'.
    '</div>';
};
```

edit: apologies for not including error message below

The error message is stating it does not recognize 2 of the data items that are available in columns, `$tonnages and $year`

```
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$tonneCount
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$year
```

Comment: This could be done with a raw query. https://laravel.com/docs/6.0/queries#raw-expressions

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: What is "$cargodb" ?

Comment: `produces errors` - what errors? What is your question? Nobody can help if you don't tell us your problem.  Please visit the help centre and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and how to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

From the query statement,

```sql
SELECT 
    terminal, 
    month,
    SUM(CASE WHEN year = YEAR(CURDATE())     THEN tonneCount ELSE 0 END) tonnage_cy,
    SUM(CASE WHEN year = YEAR(CURDATE()) - 1 THEN tonneCount ELSE 0 END) tonnage_ly
--...
```

The fields in the resultset are `terminal`, `month`, `tonnage_cy` and `tonnage_ly`

You're however attempting to retrieve values from unselected field.

Seeing that you want to retrieve the sum of tonne counts per month-year, I suggest to include `year` as a group key in the select fields  and simplify the aggregation like so:

```sql
SELECT 
    terminal, 
    month,
    year, 
    SUM(tonneCount) AS tonneCount
FROM volumes
WHERE year = YEAR(CURDATE()) - 1 OR year = YEAR(CURDATE())
GROUP BY year, terminal, month
ORDER BY month DESC
```